# Customize Ubuntu Install or select what to install

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Is there a way I can customize what I have installed when installing Ubuntu? I thought it was possible ... but maybe I didn't notice a Advanced button?

Like I want a web server, but maybe I dont want any of those games etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for [Ubuntu Minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) it is only 10MB or so but it downloads the packages you select to install during the install.